# Erro ao adicionar " 0 " em um campo tinyint(1) no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Em meu banco de dados na tabela usuarios, tenho um campo chamado status, cujo o tipo é tinyint(1). Sendo que se o status for "0" o usuario esta ativado(pode acessar o site), se o status for "1", desativado.
Porém ao fazer um INSERT e setar o status ="0" da erro.

> Minha duvida é, porque isso acontece, e como fazer com que ele aceite o 0.

O mais estranho é que ja desenvolvi outros sites, cujo uso essa mesma lógica e aceita o " 0 " tranquilamente

Segue o código:

> Cógigo que fica na pagina de usuários:

```
    $tabela = "usuarios";
    $dados = array(
        'usuario' => $p_usuario,
        'senha' => $hash_senha,
        'status' => "0",
        'permissao' => "0",
        'data_criacao' => $data_modificacao,
        'data_modificacao' => $data_modificacao
    );
    $sql_ins_usuarios_resultado = adicionar($tabela, $dados);
```

> Código que fica em outra pagina chamada por function:

```
// Armazenas os dados do array
$adc_campos = array_keys($adc_dados);
// contagem dos campos existentes
$adc_n_campos = count($adc_dados);
// Inicia a sintaxe
$adc_sintaxe = "INSERT INTO ".$adc_tabela." (";
//monta o resto da estrutura
for($adc_aux=0; $adc_aux<$adc_n_campos; $adc_aux++){
    $adc_sintaxe.= $adc_campos[$adc_aux].", ";
}
//retira a ultima virgula
$adc_sintaxe = substr($adc_sintaxe, 0, -2);
// fecha os campos e adciona o VALUES na sintaxe
$adc_sintaxe .= ") VALUES (";
//adiciona os valores na sintaxe
for($adc_aux=0; $adc_aux<$adc_n_campos; $adc_aux++){
    $adc_sintaxe.= ":".$adc_campos[$adc_aux].", ";
}
// Retira a ultima virgula
$adc_sintaxe = substr($adc_sintaxe, 0, -2);
// Fim da sintaxe
$adc_sintaxe .= ")";
// chama a função global para fazer conexão com o Banco de dados
global $conexaobd;
// prepara a sintaxe
$adc_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($adc_sintaxe);
// seta os valores de cada campo
for($adc_aux=0; $adc_aux<$adc_n_campos; $adc_aux++){
    if(!$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]){
        $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = NULL;
    }
    $adc_preparado -> bindParam(":".$adc_campos[$adc_aux], $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]);
}
return $adc_preparado->execute();
//Para debugar o código (retirar o return do $adc_preparado->execute()
        /*-->*/  //  $adc_preparado->debugDumpParams();
```

> Ao acionar o debugDumpParams() a sintaxe fica o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha, status, permissao, data_criacao, data_modificacao) VALUES (:usuario, :senha, :status, :permissao, :data_criacao, :data_modificacao) Params: 6 Key: Name: [8] :usuario paramno=-1 name=[8] ":usuario" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [6] :senha paramno=-1 name=[6] ":senha" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [7] :status paramno=-1 name=[7] ":status" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [10] :permissao paramno=-1 name=[10] ":permissao" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [13] :data_criacao paramno=-1 name=[13] ":data_criacao" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [17] :data_modificacao paramno=-1 name=[17] ":data_modificacao" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

Comment: Mostre o código do INSERT.

Comment: @bfavaretto feito!

Comment: Putz, dá pra incluir também o SQL gerado por esse PHP? Um exemplo que esteja dando o erro citado.

Comment: veja se agora te ajuda

Comment: Talvez porque o tipo do parâmetro seja string? Tenta mudar "0" para 0 lá no array

Comment: @bfavaretto nada muda :C

Comment: Eu não tava confiando muito mesmo rs. Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: @bfavaretto não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro, o mais estranho é que se eu coloco 1 invés do 0 funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Mas salva o que quando você passa zero? Null? Send for, coloca o campo como not null

Comment: @bfavaretto ele não adiciona nada, o campo já esta como not NULL

Comment: Bom, a query está falhando, pode ser por vários motivos. Tem de dar um jeito do seu programa cuspir a mensagem de erro do banco de dados.

Comment: E se botar o 0 como default nesse campo no MySQL e omitir o campo quando for dar um insert?

Comment: Pode ser besteira.. mas comente essa condição if(!$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]){
        $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = NULL;
    } e veja se o "0" irá ir pro banco

Comment: @AndersonHenrique, pow meu funcionou, mas essa linha é necessária :C

Comment: @vamos la Gabriel oque está acontecendo é que aí é uma condição do tipo boolean certo? então no momento que você faz isso if(!valor) quando cai zero, zero é false em boolean e 1 é true, quando cai zero seria tipo if(0 == false ) pois você colocou um ! antes, ai entra dentro do if certo?

Comment: @AndersonHenrique, sim isso mesmo tinha feito uma sintaxe parecida com essa ai agora. Enfim, ME ajudou, pode postar sua resposta! :D

Comment: Postado Irmão Obrigado @GabrielFilippi

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado pela tentativa!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oque você poderia fazer é o seguinte volte o 0 como String "0" igual aqui 'status' => "0", 'permissao' => "0" e dentro desse if que você fez faça essa verificação

```
if(!$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]){ 


   if($adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] == "0" ){ 
      $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = 0 
    } 

 $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = NULL; 
 }
```

e coloque isso em else

```
$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = NULL;
```

Comment: Eu que agradeço por sua ajuda.